# Keyboard and scroll problems on forms in iOS

Tags: ios, css, scroll, keyboard, ionic3

I'm having a problem with on iOS quite unusual - on a form-style screen when I need to type information into a field, the keyboard pops up, but the screen doesn't go up nor allow scrolling, making it impossible to see what I'm typing.

In CSS, I'm using this within classes:

```
overflow-x: scroll -webkit-overflow-scrolling touch;
overflow: hidden -webkit-transform translate3d (0,0,0);
```

The curious thing is that ***on Android is normal***...

Why is this happening? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard on iOS behaves in a very *special* way, here's a quote from a great article on this topic [The Eccentric Ways of iOS Safari with the Keyboard](https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d):

> The fundamental problem is that when the soft keyboard appears due to a user tap on a text input box near the bottom of the screen, **Safari doesn’t resize the browser window but instead moves it upward such that it is partially offscreen**

You're likely preventing the body to move up, so make sure there's no code that would interfere with that.

Comment: Thank you so much!